# How to call ViewModel class with constructor from View class

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a problem calling the viewmodel on my view.

When calling the viewmodel class, I did something like this.

View Page .cs:

```
public partial class Login : Page
    {
        public Login()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new LoginViewModel();
        }
    }
```

My ViewModel class:

```
public LoginViewModel()
        {
            // TO DO
        }
```

Basically it will work.

However, when I add a dependency injection on my ViewModel,

```
public LoginViewModel(IDateTimeService dateTimeService)
        {
            _dateTimeService = dateTimeService; 

            string todo = _dateTimeService.GetDateTimeString();

        }
```

How should I call it from my View?

```
public partial class Login : Page
    {
        public Login()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.DataContext = new LoginViewModel(with_interface)
        }

    }
```

I am new to WPF MVVM. Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: If you have constructor-injection you need to add the ViewModel as an parameter to the view-constructor.
`public Login(LoginViewModel loginViewModel)`.
Construction / initialization routine of the view might require adjustment thereafter.

Comment: @user18257947: You either need to construct an `IDateTimeService` in the view or inject the view with an `IDateTimeService`.